# Can I create an array of sets?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, set

Here is what I am trying to do.

I am reading in a list of words with each having a level of complexity. Each line has a word followed by a comma and the level of the word. "watch, 2" for example. I wish to put all of the words of a given level into a set to ensure their uniqueness in that level. There are 5 levels of complexity, so ideally I'd like an array with 5 elements, each of which is a set.

I can then add words to each of the sets as I read them in. Later on, I wish to pull out a random word of a specified level.

I'm happy with everything except how to create an array of sets. I've read several other posts here that seem to agree that this can't be done exactly as I would hope, but I can't find a good work around. (No, I'm not willing to have 5 sets in a switch statement. Goes against the grain.)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to all who commented. I'm now working with my chosen answer and if that doesn't pan out, I'll be back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a map . Use level as key and value as the set which contains the words. This will help you to pull out the value for a given level, When a random word is requested from a level, get the value(set in this case) using the key which is the level and pick a random value from that. This will also scale if you increase the number of levels

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Set<String>> levelSet = new HashMap();
    //Your code goes here to get the level and word
    //
    String word="";
    int level=0;
    addStringToLevel(levelSet,word,level);

    }

    private static void addStringToLevel(Map<Integer, Set<String>> levelSet,
            String word, int level) {
        if(levelSet.get(level) == null)
        {
            // this means this is the first string added for this level
            // so create a container to hold the object
            levelSet.put(level, new HashSet()); 
        }

        Set<String> wordContainer = levelSet.get(level);
        wordContainer.add(word);
    }

    private static String getStringFromLevel(Map<Integer, Set<String>> levelSet,
            int level) {
        if(levelSet.get(level) == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Set<String> wordContainer = levelSet.get(level);
        return "";// return a random string from wordContainer`
    }
```

Comment: I am not so sure about this . if there is a different value with the same key does it not overwrite the older value

Comment: @user1801279 - No, it adds the new value to the set at the given key, first creating an empty set at that key if necessary.

Comment: The issue of the same word existing twice but having been given a different level is one I fully appreciate and that is a question for another day. It might well be perfectly valid to have the same word in more than one list. Given this, I may well use this solution. One question, does the creation of wordContainer create a copy of the set or a pointer to it?

Comment: new Hashset() will allocate memory for a hashsetObject and will return the reference(memory address) of this object. So both object and refernce are created. You can visualize it as you keep a box(wordContainer) inside a big box(levelSet map)

Comment: FYI, this is a reimplementation of SetMultimap.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    private Set<String>[] process(List<String> words) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Set<String>[] arrayOfSets = new Set[5];

        for(int i=0; i<arrayOfSets.length; i++) {
            arrayOfSets[i] = new HashSet<String>();
        }

        for(String word: words) {
            int index = getIndex(word);
            String val = getValue(word);

            arrayOfSets[index].add(val);
        }

        return arrayOfSets;
    }

    private int getIndex(String str) {
        //TODO Implement
        return 0;
    }

    private String getValue(String str) {
        //TODO Implement
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: `for` loop for creation would be convenient

Comment: I like the simplicity of this one [given the use of a for look to add each new HashSet()]. However, as with the first solution, Eclipse doesn't like it and I've decided to wait until I have a better understand of Java in general before arguing with the compiler.

Comment: Could be just warnings because of the generics not being specified.  I've added an outline of code that word work with this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

#### Consider using a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of an array.

Doing so might make your life easier.

```
List<Set<String>> wordSetLevels = new ArrayList();

// ...
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  wordSetLevels.add(new HashSet<String>());
}
wordSetLevels = Collections.unmodifiableList(wordSetLevels);

// ...
wordSetLevels.get(2).add("watch");
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that the code must check that the `Set` exists for each position or pre-create them. Given a fixed number of `Sets` I would lean towards an array instead of a list to preclude the `NullPointerException` possibility.

Comment: @JohnB - I'm not sure that using an array addresses your objection to using a `List`. An array also requires one to check that each position is not `null` or else precreate a `Set` for each position. A `List` can be created with a set number of positions and it's generally good to foster the habit of not mixing arrays and collection framework objects (although harmless in this particular case).

Comment: My point is that since an array is fixed size, it can be created and populated once and thereby prevent a risk of a position not being populated. Since a List's size can change there is a risk of an NPE. Also, since Lists allow for insert at an index, the entire positional characteristic of the structure can be wrecked. Given the static nature of the desired structure, this seems like a good use of array (or `SetMultimap` as I suggest).

Comment: I think that I understand this, but Eclipse really isn't happy about it. Even with warnings turned off it is still complaining and as my level of understanding isn't high enough yet to enter into a discussion with you guys about the causes and solutions to this problem, I'm going opt for one of the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use Guava, try [SetMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html). It will take care of everything for you.

```
 SetMultimap<Integer, String> map = HashMultimap.create();
 map.put(5, "value");
```

The collection will take care of creating the inner `Set` instances for you unlike the array or `List` solutions which require either pre-creating the `Sets` or checking that they exist.

Comment: I knew I'd used a data structure like the one described in the question before!

Comment: Interesting answer. I'm going to try to minimise my use of external packages for now as the object of the exercise is for me to learn rather than to use an easier solution.